# Tcp error 995 during DataCacheFactory.GetCache

Tags: wcf, appfabric-cache

When I call the GetCache("cachename") on my DataCacheFactory to access my Windows Server AppFabric Cache 1.1, an exception occures in my Wcf trace.
The cache object returned is ok, I can use the cache and everything seems to be ok.

What could be the reason for this exception?

```
Exception: CommunicationObjectAbortedException
Message: A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.
```

Wcf Trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-20T15:37:37.2055385Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{d0eec36d-5527-4abd-b474-44361454805e}" />
<Execution ProcessName="xxxxxxxxxx" ProcessID="5648" ThreadID="13" />
<Channel />
<Computer>xxxxxxxx</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>xxxxxxxxxx</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationAsyncFailure(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>3E3</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```